# BigQuery command line find all tables across all datasets with a specific regex

Tags: shell, google-bigquery

Is there a way using `bq ls` to find all tables across every datasets with a specific `REGEX` such as `LIKE %backup%` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use @Bihag's suggestion. However, it seems that additional works are needed for the result you want.

For example,

```bash
gcloud asset list \
  --format=json \
  --project=your-project \
  --asset-types=bigquery.googleapis.com/Table \
  | jq ".[].name" | grep "backup"
```

Another way you may consider is to use [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#scope_and_syntax) view.
If you run below query in BigQuery console, you will get the filtered result using `LIKE` operation.

```sql
-- filter_table.sql
SELECT table_catalog AS project,
       table_schema AS dataset,
       table_name AS table
  FROM `{your-project}.region-{region}.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`
 WHERE table_name LIKE '%backup%';
```

you can run the above query in the CLI with `bq query` command as well.

```
$bq query --use_legacy_sql=false < filter_table.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use google cloud asset api to get the desired output.

see below, this basically accepts at project level, organisation level too. see documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/asset)

Below will give all datasets:

```
gcloud asset list --project='yourprojectid' --asset-types='bigquery.googleapis.com/Dataset'
```

Below command will give all tables under all datasets under given project

```
gcloud asset list --project='yourprojectid' --asset-types='bigquery.googleapis.com/Table'
```

hope this helps.